# Separate table of appendices - Captions not displayed in new list

Tags: koma-script, appendices

I used a previous approach to create a separate list of appendices that also shows up in the TOC. Described here: [Appendix in scrreprt - Separate table of appendices but mentioned in original TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150281/appendix-in-scrreprt-separate-table-of-appendices-but-mentioned-in-original-to)

However, I did some modifications so that new entries into the appendix list are created when the table/figure commands are used instead of chapter or section commands. This works fine, but I`m not able to include the table or figure captions into the new list of appendices. So far, only e.g. "Table S1" is displayed.

[image]

The problem is that I`m missing the command to call the captions in the following line:

> \newcommand*{\thackedtableaddcontentsline}[3]{\oldaddcontentsline{loa}{#2}{\tableformat~~}}

Does anyone know how to handle this? Thanks for any helps or suggestions. Regards

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc,chapterprefix=true,appendixprefix=false]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}          
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Basic changes to directories
% Continuous numbering 
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}

% "Table/Figure..."
\KOMAoption{listof}{entryprefix}
\newcaptionname{english}{\listoflotentryname}{Table}
\newcaptionname{english}{\listoflofentryname}{Figure}

%% --- List of Appendices ---

% Set the name for the list of appendices (LoA) that can be recalled through the command \listofappendices
\newcommand\appendicesname{Appendices}
\newcommand\listofloaname{List of \appendicesname}
\newcommand*{\listofappendices}{\listoftoc{loa}}

% Redefine LOA 
\preto\listofappendices{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \addtocontents{loa}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\vspace{2ex}\par}%
}

% Add LoA to ToC
\setuptoc{loa}{totoc}   

%% Redefine all Table or Figure commands so to be added to the LoA instead of to the LOT or LOF, when issuing the \appendix command
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
\renewcommand*{\tableformat}{\tablename~S\arabic{table}} 
\renewcommand*{\figureformat}{\figurename~S\arabic{figure}}

\let\oldaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\newcommand*{\thackedaddcontentsline}[3]{\oldaddcontentsline{loa}{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand*{\thackedtableaddcontentsline}[3]{\oldaddcontentsline{loa}{#2}{\tableformat~~}}

\let\oldaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\newcommand*{\fhackedaddcontentsline}[3]{\oldaddcontentsline{loa}{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand*{\fhackedtableaddcontentsline}[3]{\oldaddcontentsline{loa}{#2}{\figureformat~~}}

% Redefine Lable for Tables
\let\oldtable\table
\renewcommand*\table{%
\let\addcontentsline\thackedtableaddcontentsline%
\oldtable%
}
\let\oldendtable\endtable
\renewcommand*\endtable{%
\oldendtable%
\let\addcontentsline\oldaddcontentsline%
}
% redefine Lable for Figures
\let\oldfigure\figure
\renewcommand*\figure{%
\let\addcontentsline\fhackedtableaddcontentsline%
\oldfigure%
}
\let\oldendfigure\endfigure
\renewcommand*\endfigure{%
\oldendfigure%
\let\addcontentsline\oldaddcontentsline%
}

}
\makeatother 

% - main document
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\listofappendices
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section title}

\begin{table}[!hbt]
\caption[Short caption for LOT]{Long caption in the main text} 
\vspace{1ex}\centering\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Formen & Städte\\
\hline
\hline
Quadrat &  Bunkenstedt \\
\hline
Dreieck &  Laggenbeck\\
\hline
Kreis &  Peine\\
\hline
Raute & Wakaluba \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table1}
\vspace{2ex}\end{table}

\chapter{Results}
\section{Section title}

\newpage
\begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
 \noindent\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} 
 \caption{Example figure}
 \label{figure1}
\end{figure} 

%% - Appendix 
\cleardoublepage
\appendix

%Reset Figure/Table numbering
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}

\addchap{Appendix}  
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\section*{Supplemental Tables}

\begin{table}[!hbt]
\caption[Caption of Supplemental Table not pictured in LOA]{Long caption in the main text} 
\vspace{1ex}\centering\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Formen & Städte\\
\hline
\hline
Quadrat &  Bunkenstedt \\
\hline
Dreieck &  Laggenbeck\\
\hline
Kreis &  Peine\\
\hline
Raute & Wakaluba \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{Appendix1}
\vspace{2ex}\end{table}

\newpage
\section*{Supplemental Figures}

\begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
 \noindent\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} 
 \caption[Caption of Supplemental Figure not pictured in LOA]{Long caption in the main text}
 \label{Appendix2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand what you want to do. But here is a suggestion using package `scrwfile` that is part of the KOMA-Script bundle.

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc,chapterprefix=true,appendixprefix=false,
  listof=entryprefix,
  english
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}

% caption names
\newcaptionname{english}{\listoflotaentryname}{\listoflotentryname}
\newcaptionname{english}{\listoflofaentryname}{\listoflofentryname}
\newcaptionname{english}{\appendicesname}{Appendices}
\newcaptionname{english}{\appendixtablename}{Supplemental Tables}
\newcaptionname{english}{\appendixfigurename}{Supplemental Figures}

\usepackage{scrwfile}
\TOCclone[\protect\appendixtablename]{lot}{lota}
\removefromtoclist[TOCclone]{lota}
\addtotoclist[float]{lota}
\setuptoc{lota}{leveldown}
\unsettoc{lota}{totoc}
\addtocontents{lota}{\protect\value{tocdepth}=0}

\TOCclone[\protect\appendixfigurename]{lof}{lofa}
\removefromtoclist[TOCclone]{lofa}
\addtotoclist[float]{lofa}
\setuptoc{lofa}{leveldown}
\unsettoc{lofa}{totoc}
\addtocontents{lofa}{\protect\value{tocdepth}=0}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\appendix}{%
  \addchap{\appendicesname}
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
  \setcounter{table}{0}
  \pretocmd\thetable{S}{}{}
  \pretocmd\thefigure{S}{}{}
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\value{tocdepth}=0}% note that this is cloned in lota
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\value{tocdepth}=0}% note that this is cloned in lofa
  \addtocontents{lota}{\protect\value{tocdepth}=1}%
  \addtocontents{lofa}{\protect\value{tocdepth}=1}%
}{}{}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\addchap{List of \appendicesname}
\listoflota
\listoflofa

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section title}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering\rule{5cm}{1cm}
  \caption[Short caption for LOT]{Long caption in the main text} 
\end{table}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Results}
\section{Section title}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering\rule{5cm}{1cm}
  \caption{Example figure}
\end{figure} 
\Blindtext
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering\rule{5cm}{1cm}
  \caption{Example figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering\rule{5cm}{1cm}
  \caption[Short caption for LOT]{Long caption in the main text} 
\end{table}

%% - Appendix 
\appendix
\addsec*{\appendixtablename}
\begin{table}[!hbt]
  \centering\rule{5cm}{1cm}
  \caption[Caption of Supplemental Table not pictured in LOA]{Long caption in the main text} 
\end{table}

\clearpage
\addsec*{\appendixfigurename}
\begin{figure}[!hbt]
  \centering\rule{5cm}{1cm}
  \caption[Caption of Supplemental Figure not pictured in LOA]{Long caption in the main text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!hbt]
  \centering\rule{5cm}{1cm}
  \caption[Caption of Supplemental Figure not pictured in LOA]{Long caption in the main text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Great, this is what I intended to do. Many thanks for your help!
I assume I can ignore the warnings 'loca/lota are already under control of toc basic'? Just for clarification: In contrast to the previous approach we are cloning the LOT and LOF, right? This means I also dont have to worry that e.g. longtables are not automatically included in the LOA?

Comment: @Seb48 I have changed the code. So now there is only the warning regarding the alpha status of `scrwfile`. And yes, longtables in appendix are also automatically in `lota`.