# Change KOMA Script Chapter Heading Font Size locally

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

Is there a way to change the size of a KOMA Script class locally, in my case for the Appendix? I use the packet option headings=small and would like to make the chapter headings of my Appendix even smaller if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: What about setting the koma font for your appendix accordingly? Please post a MWE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1. Smaller fontsize in headings only**

Just use `\addtokomafont{chapter}{\small}` after you start the appendix-part by using the command `\appendix`:

```
\documentclass[headings=small]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}
\blindtext \blindtext

\appendix

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\small} %% Here it goes

\chapter{foo}
\blindtext \blindtext

\chapter{bar}
\blindtext \blindtext

\end{document}
```

Text:

[image]

Appendix:

[image]

**2. Smaller fontsize in headings and text**

If you want all text in appendices to be set in a smaller fontsize, and adjust all spacing accordingly use the `\KOMAoption{fontsize=size}` at the same place:

```
\documentclass[headings=small]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}
\blindtext \blindtext

\appendix

\KOMAoption{fontsize=9pt}       %% Smaller everything

\chapter{foo}
\blindtext \blindtext

\chapter{bar}
\blindtext \blindtext

\end{document}
```

Example:

[image]