# Display appendix section title like "Appendix A My Code Listing"?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, koma-script, appendices

I'm using the document class `scrartcl` and `appendix`. This currently results in a letter instead of a number for section enumeration in the TOC and section title ("A  My Code Listing").
I need to change this to "Appendix A     My Code Listing", i.e. add the word "Appendix" to the section title.

I have found a manual workaround on http://web.reed.edu/cis/help/latex/thesis#appendices but would like to know if there is a way to change this automatically.

Comment: should it as "Appendix ..." in the table of contents, too?

Comment: Actually, there should be a seperate table of contents for the appendices. But I'm not into LaTeX so much, so I cannot make much of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/list-of-appendices.

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass[toc=left]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{foo} bar

\appendix
\gdef\thesection{Appendix \Alph{section}}
\section{foo} bar
\section{foo} bar

\end{document}
```

Comment: One should note, that this also adds “Appendix” to every reference to an appendix (e.g. in the toc or via `\ref`).

Comment: @Caramdir As well as to subsections of appendices. It also seems to mess up the spacing in the toc, i.e. the extra space required by "Appendix" is not accounted for.

Answer (score 7):

KOMA-Script has a mechanism for this. If you use `scrreprt` or `scrbook`, then you only need to add the `appendixprefix` option to `\documentclass`. For `scrartcl`, there is a description in the manual (section 16.3 “Expert Commands”): Just add

```
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand*{\appendixmore}{%
  \renewcommand*{\othersectionlevelsformat}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{section}}{\appendixname~}{}%
    \csname the##1\endcsname\autodot\enskip}
  \renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{%
    \appendixname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}
}
```

to your preamble.

Comment: The `appendixmore` trick does not appear to be working in recent version of KOMA (3.19a).

Comment: With current version replace `\renewcommand*{\othersectionlevelsformat}{…}` with `\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\appendixname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}`

Answer (score -1):

You should use `\KOMAoptions{appendixprefix=true}`.
This behavior is documented in the KOMA-Script guide, as `scrartcl` is part of KOMA-Script.
The `\appendixmore`-trick is not needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work with `scrartcl` (version `2011/06/16 v3.09a`): `! Package scrkbase Error: unknown KOMA option 'appendixprefix'.` This is even [documented in the manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguien.pdf#page=123), as [Caramdir pointed out](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8463/3323).