# 'Appendix' before the appendix name

Tags: appendices

I'm having a few problems with the `appendix` in my thesis. Right now I have the following setup

```
\documentclass[english]{uvamath}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}

normal chapters etc.

\begin{appendix}
\addappheadtotoc
\chapter{Name}
text
\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

The problem now is that the chapter title shows as 'A. Name', but I would like it to be 'Appendix A. Name' (in the TOC as well as in the appendix itself). Also, I want to have 'Appendices' above the appendix section. This is already the case in the TOC because of `\addappheadtotoc`

but not in the appendix itself. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you had a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8453/display-appendix-section-title-like-appendix-a-my-code-listing?rq=1

Answer (score 10):

This is described in the `appendix`-documentation, section 2. Use the `appendices`-environment, and put a few arguments when loading the package. I think it looks wierd calling both `title` and `titletoc`, so I would advice against it.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[english]{book}
\usepackage[title,toc,titletoc,page]{appendix}
\begin{document}
normal chapters etc.
\tableofcontents
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Name}
text
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you advise against calling both title and titletoc, why are you doing it here? Oh, I guess because you just wanted to show what options are available.