# ref references the correct number, but nameref uses the wrong name

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, counters, nameref

This is my first question, so I'm sorry if there are detiails missing or my question could be written more clearly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I want to use hyperref to reference the name of one of my Appendices such that I can write:

```
...detailed information is found in \nameref{App:B}
```

And have the result be

```
...detailed information is found in Appendix B - Matlab Code
```

The thing is, my appendices are unnumbered so I have used \refstepcounter to increment the chapter counter manually. Now, when I use \ref to reference the appendix the outputted number is correct but when using \nameref, the compiled name is the last numbered chapter.

I have narrowed down the issue to have something to do with \refstepcounter redefining \ @currentlabel but even so I really struggle with understanding the exact details of what \refstepcounter has done to my \label and how to fix it.

My current code says something in the lines of

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}
\begin{document}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\chapter{Some numbered chapter}


\chapter*{Appendix B - Matlab Code}
\refstepcounter{chapter}\label{App:B}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix B - Matlab Code}
```

Comment: I would Like them to show up as "Appendix A" and not e.g. "6 Appendix A". Maybe this is not the best way to do it.

Comment: don't show "something in the lines". Show a full, exact example that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: See ['Appendix' before the appendix name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/317500/5764) and [Display appendix section title like "Appendix A My Code Listing"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8453/5764); the latter uses KOMA-script.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's pretty convoluted since it's across multiple documents, but I believe what I wrote includes all the important parts. Perhaps my wording was bad. I'll update it.

Comment: Even if it does include the important parts: I have never the time nor the will to try to create a suitable test document from your snippets.  But generally it is a bad idea to call \refstepcounter and \addcontentsline manually. This indicates that your setup is not correct.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I understand that. What would you do if not writing up the important parts then? I'm only asking because I haven't done this before and would like to know for next time. What's the easiest way when the preamble and function etc. is spread out across multiple documents?

Comment: Copy them from the various files in one test file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is, that you try to fake numbered chapters with commands for not numbered chapters. Instead you should use `\chapter{…}` and configure the output to what you want. For example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\tocchapapp}{}
\AddToHook{scrreprt/appendix}{%
  % Code from https://sf.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_TocAppendixPrefix/
  \renewcommand*{\tocchapapp}{\chapapp\ }%
  \addtocontents{\csname ext@toc\endcsname}{%
    \string\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth+=5em]{chapter}{chapter}%
  }%
  % Additionally add the prefix to the format of the headings:
  \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\appendixname\ \thechapter\ --\ }%
  % and the format of the running heads:
  \renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\appendixname\ \thechapter\ --\ }%
}
% Again Code from https://sf.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_TocAppendixPrefix/
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}{% keine Nummer:
    \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}% wie bisher
  }{% mit Nummer:
    \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{\tocchapapp#1}{#2}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Some numbered chapter}
See \autoref{App:B}: \nameref{App:B}

\appendix
\chapter{Matlab Code}
\label{App:B}
\end{document}
```

[image: table of contents, one chapter and one appendix chapter]