# Remove dots from appendix chapter numbering in KOMA-Script 3.34

Tags: numbering, koma-script, chapters, appendix, scrreprt

I would like to display the appendix chapter title as "Appendix A Appendixname" in the table of contents and "A Appendixname" in the text.

So far i get the right order of "A" and "Appendix" using `\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}` but an unwanted dot gets printed (i.e. "Appendix A. Appendixname) in the toc.

Previously, one could alter appendix titleformats using the [\appendixmore-trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8453/display-appendix-section-title-like-appendix-a-my-code-listing#comment879855_8463), however this functionality seems to be depreached as of KOMA-Script 3.34 (see [changelog](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/Release%203.34/)). Unfortunately i don't know enough LaTEX to find a new solution with the information presented in the changelog.

My current code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

% appendixmore-trick (not working anymore)
\newcommand*{\appendixmore}{%
  \renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\appendixname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}
  \renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{\appendixname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\section{Dolor sit amet}

\appendix

\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{Consectetur adipiscing elit}
  \chapter{Mauris euismod}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

This works apart from the unwanted dots:

[image: toc with unwanted dot after "A"]

Same for the chapter title:

[image: title with unwanted dot after "A"]

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [KOMA-Script scrbook: How to remove period after part](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102303/koma-script-scrbook-how-to-remove-period-after-part)

Comment: In part. Adding `\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\appendixname~\thechapter~~}` before `\appendix`, the dots get removed in the chapter title. However, they still appear in the toc. I also tried adding the line in the preable but this does nothing to the punctuation in the toc.

Comment: I suspect that [the highest voted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102305/48973) is more relevant to you than the accepted one, which you seem to be referencing. It mentions the `noenddot` option and also explains that `\autodot` can be removed for specific cases.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of `\appendixmore` will works with KOMA-Script version 3.34, too.

If LaTeX as of version 2021/06/01 is used with a KOMA-Script class

From [changelog of version 3.34](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/Release%203.34/)

- `\appendix` contains a LaTeX hook named `<class>/appendix`, where `<class>` is the name of the KOMA-Script class.
- This hook is executed before `\appendixmore`.
- Option `appendixprefix` (and `headings=onelineappendix` and `headings=twolineappendix`) is no longer implemented
  via `\appendixmore`, but via the LaTeX hook `<class>/appendix`.

So a user defined `\appendixmore` will be executed with KOMA-Script version 3.34, too. Additionally you can use `\newcommand\appendixmore{...}` even if you use one of the options `appendixprefix`, `headings=onelineappendix` or `headings=twolineappendix`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass
  [appendixprefix=false]
  {scrreprt}

\newcommand*{\appendixmore}{\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{This is \appendixname:\enskip}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\appendix
\chapter{Bar}
\KOMAScriptVersion
\end{document}
```

works with an uptodate KOMA-Script prerelease of version 3.34 and LaTeX as of version 2021/06/01. But with KOMA-Script version 3.33 or older you would get the error message »Command `\appendixmore` already defined.«, because the old KOMA-Script versions have defined this macro to implement the options `appendixprefix` etc.

---

The following example can be used with KOMA-Script version 3.33 or version 3.34. It removes the dot only from appendix chapters numbering and adds the prefix in ToC without an additional package:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\newcommand*{\appendixmore}{
  \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\thechapter\enskip}%
  \renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\thechapter\enskip}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\appendixtocentry}%
}

\newcommand*{\appendixtocentry}{%
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
    entrynumberformat=\appendixprefixfixintoc,
    dynnumwidth
  ]{default}{chapter}%
}
\newcommand{\appendixprefixfixintoc}[1]{%
  \def\autodot{}%
  \appendixname~#1%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\KOMAScriptVersion

\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\section{Dolor sit amet}

\appendix
\chapter{Consectetur adipiscing elit, Consectetur adipiscing elit, Consectetur adipiscing elit}
\chapter{Mauris euismod}
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get

[image]

It is also possible to use the new hook provided by KOMA-Script version 3.34:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}[2021-04-30]

\AddToHook{scrreprt/appendix}{%
  \AddToHook{cmd/chapterformat/before}{\def\autodot{}}%
  \AddToHook{cmd/chaptermarkformat/before}{\def\autodot{}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\appendixtocentry}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\appendixtocentry}{}{%
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
    entrynumberformat=\appendixprefixfixintoc,
    dynnumwidth
  ]{default}{chapter}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\appendixprefixfixintoc}{m}{%
  \def\autodot{}%
  \appendixname~#1%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\KOMAScriptVersion

\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\section{Dolor sit amet}

\appendix
\chapter{Consectetur adipiscing elit, Consectetur adipiscing elit, Consectetur adipiscing elit}
\chapter{Mauris euismod}
\end{document}
```

But may be it is better to use a generic hook of command `\appendix`: `cmd/appendix/after`. It is executed at the very end of the command body of `\appendix`. Note `\appendixmore` - if defined - would be executed before this hook.

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}[2021-04-30]

\AddToHook{cmd/appendix/after}{%
  \AddToHook{cmd/chapterformat/before}{\def\autodot{}}%
  \AddToHook{cmd/chaptermarkformat/before}{\def\autodot{}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\appendixtocentry}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\appendixtocentry}{}{%
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
    entrynumberformat=\appendixprefixfixintoc,
    dynnumwidth
  ]{default}{chapter}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\appendixprefixfixintoc}{m}{%
  \def\autodot{}%
  \appendixname~#1%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\KOMAScriptVersion

\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\section{Dolor sit amet}

\appendix
\chapter{Consectetur adipiscing elit, Consectetur adipiscing elit, Consectetur adipiscing elit}
\chapter{Mauris euismod}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to the problem:

Use the `numbers=noenddot` option of scrreprt to prevent trailing dots in the toc. In contrary to my initial plan, this removes all trailing dots throughout the numbering sceme of the  document but i am actually happy with this.

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}
```

Secondly, as linked by [schtandard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/48973/schtandard), the format of the chapter title can be changed by overwriting `\chapterformat` right before the appendix. (See also [KOMA-Script scrbook: How to remove period after part](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102303/koma-script-scrbook-how-to-remove-period-after-part))

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\appendixname~\thechapter~~}
```

Remember to change the command back to its original form if you want the following sections to be displayed in the usual way.