# Keep "Appendix #" in the appendix title, but remove the appendix from the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, tocloft, quotchap

I'm writing a PhD thesis, and my university requires that I list the appendices in a "List of Appendices" (LOA) that is separate from the main table of contents (TOC). I've successfully created a LOA using the `tocloft` package. The problem is that the appendices are still also listed in the TOC.

One unsatisfactory workaround is to use the asterisk'ed forms of `\chapter` and `\section` in the appendices. Among other reasons, I don't like this because it removes the appendix letter from the appendices' title pages.

How can I keep the appendix numbers in the LOA, but remove them from the TOC?

I am using the `appendices`, `tocloft` and `quotchap` packages.

Below is a minimal compilable example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{quotchap}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{appendix}

\newlistof{appendixchapter}{apx}{List of Appendices}

\newcommand{\appendixchapter}[1]{%
  % These three lines are needed to list the appendix letter in the List Of
  % Appendices even when using \chapter*
  \refstepcounter{appendixchapter}%
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \providecommand{\DOTIS}[1]{\DOCH \DOTI{#1}}

  % '*' removes the appendix from the table of contents.
  \chapter*{#1}

  % Lists the appendix in the List of Appendices.
  \addcontentsline{apx}{appendixchapter}{Appendix \protect\numberline{\theappendixchapter}#1}\par%
  \vspace {-1.47cm}}

\renewcommand{\theappendixchapter}{\Alph{appendixchapter}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listofappendixchapter\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Appendices}

\chapter{My first chapter}
This is Chapter 1's body.

\appendixchapter{My first appendix}
This is Appendix A's body.

\appendixchapter{My second appendix}
This is Appendix B's body.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add to your question a minimal, schematic version of your code showing the relavant code: documnet class used, relevant packages, and the way you are building your appendices and the new LoA.

Comment: Have you tried the workaround described in the first code snippet in the question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8211/575 ?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina done.

Comment: @SuperElectric: my answer adapts perfectly to your situation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's really no need to define a new command for the chapter in the appendices section; just before the appendices you can redefine the `\@chapter` command (defined in `report.cls`), to include the appendices in the new list instead of including them in the ToC; here's an example of such a redefinition; note that the second mandatory argument of `\newlistof` must be used in the redefinition of `\chapter` (see the lines marked with `%NEW`):

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{quotchap}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{appendix}

\newlistof{appendixchapter}{apx}{List of Appendices}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listofappendixchapter
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Appendices}

\chapter{My first chapter}
This is Chapter 1's body.

\appendix

\makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{apx}{chapter}%NEW
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{apx}{chapter}{#1}%NEW
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\makeatother

\chapter{My first appendix}
This is Appendix A's body.

\chapter{My second appendix}
This is Appendix B's body.

\end{document}
```

An excerpt from the resulting document showing the ToC and the LoA:

[image]

[image]

As requested, here's the code necessary to use a new command `\appendixchapter` (similar to `\chapter`) for the appendices; the new definition needs two new commands `\appendixchapter` and `\@appendixchapter`; only the first one will be used in the document body:

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{quotchap}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{appendix}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\appendixchapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@appendixchapter\@schapter}
\def\@appendixchapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{apx}{chapter}%NEW
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{apx}{chapter}{#1}%NEW
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\makeatother

\newlistof{appendixchapter}{apx}{List of Appendices}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listofappendixchapter
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Appendices}

\chapter{My first chapter}
This is Chapter 1's body.

\appendix


\appendixchapter{My first appendix}
This is Appendix A's body.

\appendixchapter{My second appendix}
This is Appendix B's body.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @SuperElectric: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm getting greedy: is it possible to fix the problem by defining a special command (e.g. `\appendixchapter`), rather than redefining the existing `\chapter`? This would allow one to put the definition of `\appendixchapter` in a separate source file from the main thesis body. If you or someone posts such a solution, I'd upvote & choose that.

Comment: @SuperElectric: the necessary definitions are now in my updated answer; if you are going to put these definitions in a `.sty` file, there's no need to use the commands `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother`; if they will be part of a `.tex` file, then `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother` will be necessary.