# The appendix word disappears from the table of contents when using \include

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, include, abnt, abntex2

If you compile the following minimal example which uses the `abntex2` class, which is just a wrapper around `memoir` class:

```latex
\documentclass[
12pt,
]{abntex2}

\begin{filecontents*}{beauty.tex}
\chapter{Some first}
Content.
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{appendix.tex}
\chapter{Other second}
Stuff.
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \include{beauty}
    % \chapter{Fixer}

    \begin{apendicesenv}
        \include{appendix}
    \end{apendicesenv}
\end{document}
```

You get this:

[image]

But if you uncomment the line `% \chapter{Fixer}`, then, the document is generated correctly, i.e., with the `Appendix` word on the right place:

[image]

How can I fix this behavior and keep the `Appendix` word always showing up in the table of contents regardless the contents of my file?

---

Related questions

1. [Keep "Appendix #" in the appendix title, but remove the appendix from the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38202/keep-appendix-in-the-appendix-title-but-remove-the-appendix-from-the-table)
2. [Word "Appendix" in ToC with memoir class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49905/word-appendix-in-toc-with-memoir-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `apendicesenv` environment should be within the `include`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{appendix.tex}
  \begin{apendicesenv}
    \chapter{Other second}
    Stuff
  \end{apendicesenv}
\end{filecontents}
```

I came across this kind of problem when developing the `appendix` package. I gave the solution in section 2.1 of the documentation but used a different description of the problem to that exhibited in the MWE.

Comment: It would not be nice use it like that.

Comment: @user Why not? It seems simpler than your solution and is generally applicable to cases other than yours.

Comment: Because instead of typing it only one time, I would have to type the same thing every include.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by repopulating the appendix name variable:

```latex
\makeatletter
\@ifclassloaded{abntex2}{
  \renewcommand*{\cftappendixname}{\apendicename\space\space}
}{}
\makeatother
```

Full example:

```latex
\documentclass[
12pt,
]{abntex2}

\begin{filecontents*}{beauty.tex}
\chapter{Some first}
Content.
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{appendix.tex}
\chapter{Other second}
Stuff.
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\@ifclassloaded{abntex2}{
  \renewcommand*{\cftappendixname}{\apendicename\space\space}
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \include{beauty}

    \begin{apendicesenv}
        \include{appendix}
    \end{apendicesenv}
\end{document}
```

[image]